# Bower's authors field—original authors or package maintainer

Tags: bower

I'd like to make a Bower package for a piece of software that is not mine. Bower package's description file, `bower.json`, has a field called `authors`. I couldn't find any actual description of the desired interpretation for this field, and I see at least three:

- original authors of that piece of software (ie. whom to ask for licensing, etc.),
- Package maintainer, (ie. whom to bother if there's something wrong with the package itself),
- both of the above.

Which of the above is the correct one for Bower's `authors` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"authors"` field should contain the [original authors](https://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/json.md#authors).

Comment: Currently bower.json-spec declares:
**authors Type: Array of (String or Object)**
_A list of people that authored the contents of the package._